# Is it way to hide running application from other application?

Tags: windows-10, task-manager, application-launch

I`ve migrated from Windows 8 to Windows 10. I used to play multiple Hearthstone windows in compability mode with Windows XP. But on Win10 second Blizzard launcher says "Game already running" anyway.

I need to hide game window from launcher, but not from desktop.

Comment: Why are you trying to run it multiple times?

Comment: Because I have more than 1 active account

Comment: can you create another user on the PC and "run as" that user?